# Should I say "I am unaware of neither" or "I am unaware of both"?

Tags: negation, semantics

Should I say "I am unaware of neither of A and B" or "I am unaware of both of A and B"?
In other words, is unaware negation?

Comment: “Neither A and B” is not grammatical; it must be “neither A nor B” (colloquially you’ll also sometimes hear “neither A or B”, but _nor_ is a safer bet). The second _of_ is also not necessary and just makes the sentence confusing. Whichever way you say it, “neither A nor B” and “both A and B” are the most natural-sounding phrasings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use either of those sentences. I feel like I could say any of the following: "I am unaware of both A and B", "I am unaware of either A or B", "I am not aware of either A or B" or "I am aware of neither A nor B". Any of these would express the idea "I am not aware of A and I am not aware of B".

"Unaware" is not *clausal* negation. The adjective prefix *un-* can be categorized as a form of "[subclausal negation](http://www.f.waseda.jp/yueno/SIEGch8.htm)".

A side point that I think I need to address before going on to the rest of my answer is that "neither of A and B" and "both of A and B" don't sound right to me in any kind of context. The use of *of* after quantifiers like *neither* or *both* is a bit complicated: it's necessary to use *of* before a pronoun like *them* or *us* ("neither of them" or "both of us"), but it's not always necessary in other contexts. When you are using multiple noun phrases A and B, the usual structure for *neither* is "neither A nor B", and the usual structure for *both* is "both A and B".

So in the rest of this answer, I am going to talk instead about the sentences "I am unaware of neither of A **nor** B" and "I am unaware of both A and B."

Based purely on the syntactic structure, we would expect "I am unaware of neither A nor B" to mean something different from "I am aware of neither A nor B". And since "I am aware of neither A nor B" expresses a negative concept, "I am unaware of neither A nor B" logically ought to express the negation of a negation:  "I am unaware of neither A nor B" = "I am not unaware of either A or B" = "I am aware of A and B". Using clausal and subclausal negation together like this is grammatical, but people often get confused about what it's supposed to mean.

In actual fact, we can find examples of sentences like "I am unaware of neither A nor B" being used to mean the same thing as sentences like "I am aware of neither A nor B" (= "I am not aware of either A or B").

Here is one that I found with a quick Google search:

- > The observers were unaware of the target and flankers  [...] the observers were unaware of neither the target nor the flankers.

  ("[Crowding without visual awareness](https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2136471)", by Joey Cham and Sing-Hang Cheung, Journal of Vision August 2009)

Although this particular example could just be viewed as an insignificant error, I would imagine that there are more like it. The linguist Mark Liberman has made a number of posts on the blog *Language Log* about the phenomenon of "[misnegations](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?cat=273)", and certain types seem to be produced with some regularity even by native speakers.

To make things easier on your readers, I would recommend avoiding structures like "I am unaware of neither A nor B."

Comment: If I say "I might be unaware of A, or B, or neither.", would it be OK?

Comment: @Aqqqq: I would understand that to mean that you might be unaware of either A or B, or you might be aware of both. If that's what you mean, I would prefer to put it in a way like I did in my last sentence. If you mean "I might be unaware of A, or B, or unaware of both A and B", then you should say ""I might be unaware of A, or B, or **both**".

Answer (score 2):

I would say "I am unaware of either". "Unaware" does indeed trigger negative polarity.

"I am unaware of both" is also possible, but I would only use it for emphasis.

Comment: This is a case where double negations _do_ definitely result in a positive, though: “I am unaware of neither” means “I am aware of both”.

Comment: If I say "I might be unaware of A, or B, or neither.", would it be OK?

Comment: @Aqqqq: it would probably be understood; but it is odd. I think you mean "I might be unaware of A, or B, or both".